# set instance variables for rails ActiveRecord model object does no work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Ruby on Rails model class:

```
class DeliveryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :state
end

item=DeliveryItem.new
item.instance_variable_set "@name","apple"
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for #

How do I make this work?

Comment: use item.instance_variable_get "@name"

Comment: attr_accessible :state, :name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
item.instance_variable_set(:@attributes, {'name' => 'apple'})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means you don't have a `name` attribute for `DeliveryItem`.  This means that there's no setter method for `name` or you don't have a `name` column. So to solve this issue, you have to either

- add a `name` column or
- create a setter method for `name` or
- use `attr_accessor` or `attr_writer` to do the work for you

add the following to your model

```
class DeliveryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

then you should be able to use your code

```
item = DeliveryItem.new
item.instance_variable_set "@name","apple"

# or just use item.name=
item.name = 'apple'
```

Comment: thank u for the help, the attributes i want to set are not fixed:)